# Strange behaviour when deleting object

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I have following django models:

**Customer**:

```
class Customer(BaseModel):
    """
    Represents company
    """
    company_name = models.CharField(_("Company name"), max_length=128)
```

**Profile**:

```
class Profile(BaseModel):
    """
    Model used to extend builtin user information
    """
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
```

and **ProfilePermission**, which stores m2m information about access level (each profile may access multiple customers with different access levels).

```
class ProfilePermission(BaseModel):
    """
    M2M model used to assign a users (profiles) to the customers
    """
    profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    access_level = models.CharField(_("Access level"),max_length=16,
                                    choices=ACCESS_LEVELS, default="admin")
```

Problem appears when I am trying to delete the **ProfilePermission** instance (using `.delete()` method). It works properly - ProfilePermission is deleted without touching it's foreign key fields - customer and profile.

However, when user which has that `Profile` as foreign key logs in then the magic begins.

When he is logged in, and I am trying to delete that **ProfilePermission** django wants to delete related **Profile** and **Customer** as well.

Its very strange. It behaves that way both in django bultin admin app and in our custom dashboard. Any ideas?

Comment: see here for why https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.on_delete

Comment: Why do you need `on_delete=SET_NULL` in a M2M object? Is it useful to know that the user was an admin of a customer that no longer exists?